# DiskInternal's Linux Reader Search

Tags: windows-xp, search, windows-search, file-search, reiserfs

A 2TB external hard drive having multiple reiserfs, ext2/3 and similar linux file systems on it.

In need for a quick search from within windows xp I found Linux Reader from DiskInternals. It performed ok - good for reading data or just surfing the disk.

Searching, a desaster. It was terrible. My search did not finish in three days time...

First search for files ending with *.tex was successfull and finished in acceptable time.

Second search for just a word in a filename did not finish in three days. I had to abort. I can tell it was still searching from the status bar. There was no endless loop. Filenames were being updated which were being checked but unfortunately it never was able to get out of the reiserfs partition, not for hours or for days. It just did not finish, I let it search for three days it just could not finish. The filenames were being updated in one or two seconds time.

Do you have an idea what the problem was? Simply too much files for such a slow search?

Do you know an alternative to search multiple different filesystems for a word in the filename? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the Reader from DiskInternals is recovering files - so it takes lots of time for the search. I installed total commander and DiskInternal's plugin to read linux partitions and this time the search finished within a minute.